# Why does Gridsome use Vue in the dist build?

Tags: vue.js, gridsome

I've recently come across Gridsome as a solution for building a static site in Vue and when I ran a build to test it out, I checked out all of the HTML files that were being generated and I noticed that they referenced the Vue.js script.

I assumed that Gridsome would compile all of the vue into static html/css/js so I can't figure out what requires the Vue.js framework to be loaded even in the dist build.

Answer (score 0):

This is because it uses Vue.js for the frontend. For example, if you need to fetch data from an API when the user visits the site, you would use Vue.js to do that. Same as if you wanted to hide/show fields based on a button click.